# Apply to a job through Upwork API

Tags: upwork-api

I have been using Upwork API quite a lot to build different filtering combinations and communication tools.

I couldn't find a way to Apply for a Job.

https://developers.upwork.com/

I found this: https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#contracts-and-offers_send-client-offer

which sends an offer to a freelancer, but not the other way round.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

sorry to inform you - it's impossible as of now. Apply-for-a-Job process must be completed using the site.

Answer (score 0):

I am agreeing on this,
Upwork emphasizes on valid apply job and not automated.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQnhX.png) - Only this operation is available